# Java version does not apply on Mac

Tags: macos, java

I am trying to set my machines javac version to 11 from 18.0.2 and I'm doing the following steps

1. `open ~/.zshenv`
2. `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v11)`
3. `source ~/.zshenv`

When I check the version, I still get it as 18.0.2. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: JAVA_HOME has a certain **internal** meaning to java itself.  But you should also look into what `which javac` `which java` return.  Likely macos finds the older executables in $PATH first.

Comment: Why do you need to use javac from Java 11? You can use the --release, --source, and --target options on the Java 18 javac to ensure the code is compiled for Java 11.